# Getting a Windows Transparency wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, transparency, alpha

I'm trying to get a windows transparency in wxPython. I tried **self.GetTransparent()**, however that apparently doesn't exist. So, how do I go about getting a windows transparency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to derive your own class, which will be aware of its own transparency:

```
import wx

class TransparentAwareFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.transparency = 255

    def SetTransparent(self, value):
        self.transparency = value
        wx.Frame.SetTransparent(self, value)

    def GetTransparent(self):
        return self.transparency        

class MainWindow(TransparentAwareFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        TransparentAwareFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Click me!")
        self.Show()    
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, e):
        self.SetTransparent(self.GetTransparent() - 20)

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```